# Debugging Ghidra Script

Tags: python, java, ghidra

I want to write a new script for ghidra to extract variuous information from the binary and store it to an external file for future management. I need to perform the analyisis with Ghidra Headless in order to put it in an analysis workflow with other tool. I can't found any guide/tutorial on how to correctly use eclpise to launch ghidra headless and run the current developing script. I had already installed the ghidraDev extension and it can correctly run Ghidra Gui

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase the question as to something like “How do I run Ghidra on a command line such that no STDIN (user prompt/input) happens?”